# MVVMCross add multiple dynamic properties to viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an requirement to render the screen (screen type : form) dynamically based on the service response (rather than defining the UI manually). I was able to successfully bind predefined properties to dynamically created textboxes & textviews. Following is the sample code that used to bind predefined property to dynamic textbox

```
Type myType = typeof(DynamicViewModel);
PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(nameof(dynamicProperty)); //dynamicProperty -static property in VM
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DynamicActivity, DynamicViewModel>();
set.Bind(editText).To(myPropInfo.Name); //editText - dynamically created textbox
set.Apply();
```

But the code needs to be further improved by dynamically creating the no of properties - matching with the no of UI elements dynamically created. 
The project is created using Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross's latest version. Please share the way to generate dynamic string(or object type) properties in viewmodels that can be binded with dynamically generated view elements(textboxes & textviews).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

One is using Reflection as you are doing there, but you could have performance issues.

The other way is to arrange a bit the data and model you are getting from the server to be something like you can then use some Factories to build your View/VM:

So it could be:

```cs
public enum DataType
{
    String,
    Number,
    Boolean,
    List,
    // and any other types that you need
}

public class OptionItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FieldModel
{
    public DataType Type { get; set; }

    public string DefaultValue { get; set; } // this is a serialized value

    public List<OptionItemModel> Options { get; set; } // this only applies to DataType -> List
}

public class StructureModel
{
    public List<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

So then you can have an `ObservableCollection` on your VM and your items can be created by a factory iterating for each one of the fields of the structure and so you can have custom Item View Models depending on the DataType of the field.

Then you can have a List on your View that uses a Template selector where you can create the `Cell/Row` depending on the `DataType` or the `ItemViewModel` and that would be it.

Then you can have a similar model structure to fill the values and upload them to the server.

Hope it's clear enough